# Passing env variable inputs to a reusable workflow

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to call a reusable workflow from another one, passing it some input variables. In the caller workflow I have some environment variables that I want to pass as input to the reusable one, like so:

```
env:
  SOME_VAR: bla_bla_bla
  ANOTHER_VAR: stuff_stuff

jobs:
  print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print inputs passed to the reusable workflow
        run: |
          echo "some var: $SOME_VAR"
          echo "another var: $ANOTHER_VAR"
  call_reusable:
    uses: ...
    with:
      input_var: $SOME_VAR
      another_input_var: $ANOTHER_VAR
```

the reusable workflow:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      input_var:
        required: true
        type: string
      another_input_var:
        required: true
        type: string

jobs:
  the_job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Print inputs
        run: |
          echo "input_var: ${{ inputs.input_var }}"
          echo "another_input_var: ${{ inputs.another_input_var }}"
```

The `Print inputs passed to the reusable workflow` step works fine - all variables are correctly printed. However, the `Print inputs` step in the reusable workflow (the callee) does not work as expected - all the variables are empty.

I couldn't find anything in the docs suggesting that there is something wrong with my approach so, the way I see it, this should be working. Still, looking at the logs there is something wrong, as in the reusable workflow (callee) I can see:

```
Run echo "input_var: $SOME_VAR"
  echo "another_input_var: $ANOTHER_VAR"
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
input_var: 
another_input_var:
```

I tried wrapping the values in the `with:` block in `$(echo)` but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After some researches, I found [this thread](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26671) explaining that:

> **You can’t pass ENV variables to the reusable workflow, so they are almost useless in this pattern.**

Moreover, on the [official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#limitations), it is stated that:

> Any environment variables set in an `env` context defined at the workflow level in the caller workflow **are not propagated to the called workflow**.

Therefore, in your case, you wont be able to achieve what you want using directly the `env` variable, **but there are workarounds**.

*Note: It would be great if GitHub comes up with a better way to assign values inline or pass them into reusable workflows, as handling each parameter many times just to pass it into a reusable workflow is cumbersome.*

---

A workaround could be to use **outputs** from a first job, and use those outputs as the reusable workflow inputs.

**Here is an example of how it could be done:**

```yaml
env:
  SOME_VAR: bla_bla_bla
  ANOTHER_VAR: stuff_stuff

jobs:
  print:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      some_var: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.some_var }}
      another_var: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.another_var }}   
    steps:
      - name: Print inputs passed to the reusable workflow
        id: step1
        run: |
          echo "some var: $SOME_VAR"
          echo "some_var=$SOME_VAR" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          echo "another var: $ANOTHER_VAR"
          echo "another_var=$ANOTHER_VAR" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  
  call_reusable:
    needs:
      - print
    uses: ...
    with:
      input_var: ${{ needs.print.outputs.some_var }}
      another_input_var: ${{ needs.print.outputs.another_var }}
```

*EDIT: Removed `::set-output` syntax which is now deprecated.*

That way, without updating the reusable workflow implementation, the inputs would be filled with the expected values.

Here are the workflow I used to test: [main](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester52.yml) + [reusable](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/workflow-tester52-reusable.yml)

And you can check the workflow run with the expected outcome [here](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/runs/7765595224?check_suite_focus=true).

Comment: This work-around is extremely complex for achieving such a simple action. Also, it is unusable for passing secrets because they are automatically removed from outputs.

Comment: In **reusable workflows**, you can [inherit secrets](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit), or you have to [send them to the workflow as secrets anyway](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows#using-inputs-and-secrets-in-a-reusable-workflow). Therefore, this workaround only makes sense in this context for inputs and env, not for secrets.

Comment: Is there a way to unpack all secrets into the current step's `env`? Combining that with `secrets: inherit` in the calling workflow seems like it would solve the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by unpack? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there anyway I could do this dynamically? say - i have a list of 15-20 environment variables

Comment: You could eventually use an env file as input to the reusable workflow. And have a first job in the reusable workflow that would read this file and set output for each value set into it.

Answer (score 6):

Lately GitHub introduced a feature to support variables in environment (very basic and the long awaited feature, I must say).
So other solution could be to create an environment in GitHub, create some variables under it with desired values and use the environment as needed.

Caller workflow:

```
jobs:
  Dev-Deployment:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
        environment: Development

  QA-Deployment:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
        environment: QA
```

Reusable workflow:

```
on:
 workflow_call:
  inputs:
    environment:
      type: string
      required: true

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: ${{ inputs.environment }}
    steps:
      - name: Print variables - ${{ vars.SOME_VAR }} - ${{ vars.ANOTHER_VAR }}
        run: |
            echo ${{ vars.SOME_VAR }}
            echo ${{ vars.ANOTHER_VAR }}
```

GitHub environment:
[image]

Comment: I think they might have changed it.... vars.<ID> gets changed to secrets.<ID> when the workflow is run. I can't find this documentation anywhere, but it works....

Answer (score 3):

The use of `::set-output` is now deprecated.

See https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/.

Now recommended:

```
- name: Save state
  run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_STATE

- name: Set output
  run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple experiment shows that it is not necessary to `echo` variable to the `$GITHUB_OUTPUT` and it is enough to define it just in the `outputs`

```yaml
name: Test outputs

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  BRANCH: main

jobs:
  variables:
    name: Compute outputs
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      branch: ${{ env.BRANCH }}
      # branch: ${{ steps.variables.outputs.branch }}
    steps:
      - name: Echo
        if: false
        run: echo

      # - name: Set outputs variables
      #   id: variables
      #   run: echo
      #     echo "branch=${{ env.BRANCH }}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"

  show:
    name: Show outputs
    needs: variables
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Echo outputs
        run: |
          echo "branch: ${{ needs.variables.outputs.branch }}"
```

This simplify variables pass, especially when we have a lot of them. It can be used for simple cases when we need just to pass variable value, but not for computations.

A single cons is that we need at least one step in the first job, but we can set a dummy one or disable it.