# how to read in an array of strings to matrix in github actions?

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, github-actions

I'm writing a github actions workflow where I take in an array of strings as a global env variable and want to read it in as a part of the matrix strategy.

I get the following error:

`Error when evaluating 'strategy' for job '$JOB_NAME'. .github/workflows/deploy.yaml (Line: 53, Col: 18): Error parsing fromJson,.github/workflows/deploy.yaml (Line: 53, Col: 18): Input string '9.0.0' is not a valid number. Path '[0]', line 1, position 6.,.github/workflows/deploy.yaml (Line: 53, Col: 18): Unexpected value ''`

This is what my setup currently looks like. I have the job 'prepare-matrix' set up since matrix can't access the `env` context directly.

```
env:
  VERSIONS: '[9.0.0, 11.0.0]'

jobs:
  prepare-matrix:
    name: Prepare Matrix Output
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs: 
      all_versions: ${{ steps.step1.outputs.matrix }}
    steps: 
      - name: Create Matrix Variable
        id: step1
        run: echo "matrix=${{env.VERSIONS}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

  deploy-gke:
    name: Deploy to GKE
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [prepare-matrix]
    strategy: 
      max-parallel: 2
      matrix: 
        version: ${{ fromJSON(needs.prepare-matrix.outputs.all_versions) }}
    steps:
      ...(several steps to complete job)....
```

I believe there is some formatting issue wrong somewhere either in env.VERSIONS, or in matrix.version, and I've tried changing parentheses, quotes, and removing the fromJSON(), but nothing seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Try: `VERSIONS: '["9.0.0", "11.0.0"]'`

Comment: still running into the same issue

Comment: Need to escape those quotes as well i.e. `VERSIONS: '[\"9.0.0\", \"11.0.0\"]'`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else struggling with the same problem, what ended up working was actually a simple fix - I simply needed to use ' within the array and " around it.

So the variable should be defined as:

```
VERSIONS: "['9.0.0', '11.0.0']"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the values in the `VERSIONS` array to strings:

```yaml
VERSIONS: '["9.0.0", "11.0.0"]'
```

and, then transform the whole JSON to a raw string literal for [`fromJSON`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) by escaping double quotes:

```yaml
VERSIONS: '[\"9.0.0\", \"11.0.0\"]'
```

Alternatively, you may automate this escaping using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) while setting the output i.e. with:

```yaml
VERSIONS: '["9.0.0", "11.0.0"]'
```

set output like this:

```bash
echo "matrix=$(jq -cr '@json' <<< "$VERSIONS")" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

or,

```bash
echo "matrix=$(jq -cr '@json' <<< "${{ env.VERSIONS }}")" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

See `jq`'s [Format strings and escaping](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Builtinoperatorsandfunctions) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an iOS developer, and I faced a similar challenge. However, I'm not very proficient in this, so I took a slightly different approach. I used `actions/github-script@v6` (JavaScript) to achieve my goal.

Below is the template I'd like to share:

```yaml
jobs:
  pre-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.set-matrix.outputs.result }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/github-script@v6
      id: set-matrix
      env:
        # comma-separated values
        # example: ${{ vars.YOUR_DYNAMIC_MATRIX }}
        ARRAY_STRING: "eg,1,2"
      with:
        result-encoding: string
        script: |
          // JavaScript code
          const { ARRAY_STRING } = process.env;
          var objects = ARRAY_STRING
              .split(',')
              .map(value => ({varName1: 'thing', varName2: value}) );

          // [
          //   { varName1: 'thing', varName2: 'eg' },
          //   { varName1: 'thing', varName2: '1' },
          //   { varName1: 'thing', varName2: '2' }
          // ]
          console.log(objects);
          return JSON.stringify(objects);

  main-job:
    name: "varName2: ${{ matrix.object.varName2 }}"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: pre-job
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix: 
        object: ${{ fromJson(needs.pre-job.outputs.matrix) }}
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo "varName1: ${{ matrix.object.varName1 }}"
```

Hope you enjoy.