# Pass environment variables to reusable workflow without using 1 to 1 inputs

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions

Right now, if I want to pass a environment variable to a reusable workflow I have to do something like this:

```
name: Reusable workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      my_env_var:
        required: false
        type: string
env:
  my_env_var: ${{ inputs.my_env_var }}
```

However, for this I first need to define as an input each environment variable I want to pass. This works, but having to hard code the environment variables makes my reusable workflows less generic. Is there a way to pass envs without having to define them one by one? I was thinking on something like this:

```
name: Calling reusable workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  push-image-dev:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/my-reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
      input1: ...
      input2: ...
    env:
      env1: ...
      env2: ...
```

However, I have been reading some documentation and I don't think that exists. Is there any other way of doing it, as inheriting env variables or creating a single input which is a variable dictionary, which is later parsed and sets all the env vars in the reusable workflow?

Comment: It's currently not possible to inherit env variable in reusable workflows. The workaround is indeed to use inputs for each env variable. [This thread might give you more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73305126/passing-env-variable-inputs-to-a-reusable-workflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created this simple logic which allows me to pass all the environment variables I want on a 1:N relationship with respect to inputs. I created an input which expects a list of environment variables, formatted as "env=value", and which is later converted to environment variables in a step inside the workflow.

**Calling the workflow:**

```
name: Calling reusable workflow

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  my-job:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/my-reusable-workflow.yml
    with:
      env_vars: |
        env1=value1
        env2=value2
        env3=value3
```

**Workflow definition:**

```
name: My reusable workflow
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      env_vars:
        description: List of environment variables to set up, given in env=value format.
        required: false
        type: string

jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set environment variables
        if: ${{ inputs.env_vars }}
        run: |
          for i in "${{ inputs.env_vars }}"
          do
            printf "%s\n" $i >> $GITHUB_ENV
          done
```